# Good modern paper demonstrating differentiation of glauconite and berthierine using xrd or FTIR

Tags: geology, mineralogy, sedimentology, crystallography, spectral-analysis

I'm looking for a recent paper that demonstrates how one would unambiguously differentiate glauconite from berthierine and have yet to find something useful.

I'm running across a lot of papers seeming to do this without explaining how they are going about it, an example being identification of berthierine as an alteration phase within authigenic glauconite grains. This wasn't the goal of the paper nor a key observation so I can understand why it would be skipped over or not explained in detail, but I need to find something definitive, or at least convincing, that demonstrates a method.

Additionally, a colleague of mine wrote a paper that identifies berthierine using only the 2.141A peak. However, it is my understanding that glauconite also has a 2.141A peak and the (001) basal reflection peak should be used to distinguish between the two instead. Again, need a citation for this, not a vague recollection, but some comments would be useful.